# Importing JSON or CSV file in MongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, csv, windows-7, import

I'm new to MongoDB in Windows 7 and I tried to import JSON and CSV file into MongoDB.

1.First i tried importing JSON file using the command

```
"C:\>mongodb\bin\mongoimport –host localhost:27017 –db mydb –collection docs"
```

and it showed this error

```
"exception:BSON representation of supplied JSON is too large: code FailedToParse: FailedToParse: Expecting '{': offset:0"
```

2.When i import CSV file i used the command

```
"C:\mongodb\bin>mongoimport --db mynewdb --collection message --type csv --fields
form,Iname,fistname,lastname --file d:\new folder\csv1.csv"
```

and i get the error message as

```
"ERROR: multiple occurrences
Import CSV, TSV or JSON data into MongoDB.
When importing JSON documents, each document must be a separate line of the input file"
```

I downloaded JSON and CSV  bulk file randomly by browsing. I want to know whether it will get imported when data's are non-organized  or should the data be organized? If so where can get a complete bulk JSON and CSV file which is ready to import.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the --jsonArray flag at the end of your query so it would look like

```
C:\>mongodb\bin\mongoimport –host localhost:27017 –db mydb –collection docs --jsonArray
```